# Merge two columns in var variable in one column using EF6

Tags: c#, merge, entity-framework-6, var

I have a variable as you can see here I generate it :

```
var q = qcForSearchItemCode.Select(i =>new{ itemcode1=i.Material1Itemcode,itemcode2=i.Material2Itemcode}).ToList();
```

So as you can see my q variable has two columns `Material1Itemcode`,`Material2Itemcode`.

I need to merge these two columns into one column using EF6.

The catastrophic solution is using a list and a foreach loop, but I thought maybe there is a better solution?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of property are Material1ItemCode and Material2ItemCode? Are they string,  integer or another custom type? Your merge solution will depend on it.

Comment: And you want the variable q to be a list of merged fields? Also just noticed is your string field a comma separated value?

Comment: The q variable consists two columns she need to  merge this two columns .for example itemcode1=1,2,3 and itemcode2=2,3,4 the result should be 1,2,3,4

Comment: i think the combine is a better word instead of merge

Comment: Well it's actually called a distinct union.  Try my answer below. I'm not on computer so don't mind any syntax errors. Well may be you need to convert it back to a comma separated value after distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a small `List` for each entity and then flatten the lists to one by `SelectMany`:

```
var q = qcForSearchItemCode
        .SelectMany(i =>new List<string>
                        { 
                            i.Material1Itemcode,
                            i.Material2Itemcode
                        }
                   ).ToList();
```

It creates a query containing `CROSS JOIN` and `UNION`, so it may not be the best performing solution, but probably good enough when not "too many" records are involved.

Answer (score -1):

You could do.

```
var q = qcForSearchItemCode.Select(i =>new{ item=(i.Material1Itemcode+i.Material2Itemcode).Split(',').Distinct()}).ToList();
```